# how to reset mouse and touchpad settings on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I changed default sensivity for mouse and touchpad, and I can't turn the default mouse and touchpad settings now. How can I do this?

Comment: How did you change them?

Comment: @Pilot6 from System Settings > Mouse & Touchpad

Comment: So change them back.

Comment: @Pilot6 I want to use default settings..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The peripherals settings for Unity (and Gnome) are stored using `dconf`. You can install [dconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-editor) to inspect and reset settings manually. The mouse and touchpad can be found in `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/` and `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/` respectively.

[image: dconf-editor example]

Alternatively enter the following commands into Terminal to reset all settings for mouse and touchpad:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/
```

Comment: If both `gsettings` and `dconf` options exist, better practice to use `gsettings: `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse` and `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad`.